# My function is not working and it says 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: python

```
#This is hard for me to handle; I need some one's help!


alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    inp = int(input('''1 = Make a code
    2 = Decode a message
    3 = Quit
    Enter your selection: '''))
    if inp == 1:
      def shift(offset):

    message = input("Input Message You Would Like Encrypted:\n")
    new_message = ''

    for letter in message:

        letter = letter.lower() #doesn't handle upper-case yet

        if letter.isalpha():
            shift_pos = alphabet.index(letter) + offset
            new_pos = alphabet[shift_pos]
            new_message += new_pos

        #these will not be shifted

        elif ' ' or '/t' or '/n' in letter: 
            new_message += letter

        elif letter.isnumeric(): 
            new_message += letter

        else:
            print("An error took place in recording the message. Check input.\n")

    print(new_message)


shift(-1)
if inp == 2:
  def shift(offset):

    message = input("Input Message You Would Like Encrypted:\n")
    new_message = ''

    for letter in message:

        letter = letter.lower() #doesn't handle upper-case yet

        if letter.isalpha():
            shift_pos = alphabet.index(letter) + offset
            new_pos = alphabet[shift_pos]
            new_message += new_pos

        #these will not be shifted

        elif ' ' or '/t' or '/n' in letter: 
            new_message += letter

        elif letter.isnumeric(): 
            new_message += letter

        else:
            print("An error took place in recording the message. Check input.\n")

    print(new_message)


shift(+1)
continue
```

Comment: You should start off by formatting your question correctly

Comment: It looks like `continue` is not in the loop. What do you expect it to do at the end of your code?

Comment: What loop is `continue` supposed to be part of? Your code as posted is not indented correctly, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Your indentation seems to be all over the place.  Indentation is more than stylistic in Python.  It affects how your code functions.  In your case, the posted code ends with a `continue` statement with no indentation.  That means it's at the top-level in the file.  It's meaningless.  There is no loop that it can apply to.  Hence the error.  Either delete it, or move it into a loop body.

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is messed up. It looks you have just started programming.

```py
import string

def shift(offset):
    new_message = ''
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

    for letter in message:

        letter = letter.lower() #doesn't handle upper-case yet

        if letter.isalpha():
            shift_pos = (alphabet.index(letter) + offset) % len(alphabet)
            new_pos = alphabet[shift_pos]
            new_message += new_pos

        #these will not be shifted
        elif ' ' or '/t' or '/n' in letter: 
            new_message += letter

        elif letter.isnumeric(): 
            new_message += letter

        else:
            print("An error took place in recording the message. Check input.\n")

    return new_message

while True:
    inp = int(input('''
    1 = Make a code
    2 = Decode a message
    3 = Quit
    Enter your selection: '''))

    offset = 3

    if inp == 1:
        message = input("Input Message You Would Like To Encrypt:\n")
        new_message = shift(offset)
        print(new_message)

    elif inp == 2:
        offset = -3
        message = input("Input Message You Would Like To Decrypt:\n")
        new_message = decrypted = shift(offset)
        print(new_message)

    elif inp == 3:
        break
```

I think you should read this [book](https://inventwithpython.com/cracking/)